# Spaces in Wordpress Astra not showing on SOME computers

Tags: wordpress

I'm using an Astra Wordpress Theme, and on some computers, spaces are not shown where they should appear:

[image]

On others, the spaces appear perfectly fine.
I'm baffled what goes on here.

If I add 1 more space, 1 space appears on the problematic computers, but 2 spaces appear on the other computers, which looks weird, so I need a real solution for this.

What might be the cause and a fix for this problem?

ps: I have seen this problem on other websites (not done by me), too.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be an issue with hidden characters from copied and pasted text from a text editor, such as Word?

Try coping the text and paste it into a plain text editor. Delete the text from the CMS and copy and paste in your cleaned copy.

Also, are you declaring `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the site head?

Comment: Thank you. I have added a screenshot to my post. In this screenshot you see what the html code looks like when I add this extra space to make it look ok. Can you spot something weird in there?

Comment: I did the plain-text-editor thing, and it solved the problem, thank you!